# Need Async/Await equivalent for BackgroundWorker

Tags: asynchronous-programming, async

Given the following code in the `DoWork()` event of a `BackgroundWorker` object, how can the concept be converted to the `Async/Await` model?

I wish to execute multiple downloads simultaneously in order to maximize bandwidth. I also will need to retain the ability to increment a progress bar on the dialog.

```
Dim oChunks As SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte())
Dim oFiles As List(Of FileInfo)
Dim iChunk As Integer

oChunks = New SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte())
oFiles = Service.Client.GetChunks(Me.Upload.UploadId, Me.Target)

oFiles.ForEach(Sub(File As FileInfo)
                 Worker.ReportProgress((iChunk / Me.Upload.Chunks) * 100, "Downloading...")
                 oChunks.Add(File.Name, Service.Client.GetChunk(File, Me.Target))
                 iChunk += 1
               End Sub)
```

A C# answer is welcome; I can translate.

**EDIT**

Based on Ewan's sample code, I came up with the revision below.

But it's not working correctly:

1. The downloads still run sequentially, not in parallel
2. The UI blocks during execution
3. The `Download.Progress` event doesn't fire

What am I missing?

```
Public Class Main
  Private Async Sub cmdSave_Click(Sender As Button, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Dim oChunks As SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte())
    Dim oFiles As List(Of FileInfo)
    Dim aData As Byte()

    Me.Upload = dgvUploads.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem

    pnlTarget.Enabled = False
    dlgSave.FileName = "{0}.zip".ToFormat(Me.Upload.UploadName)
    txtFile.Text = String.Empty

    If dlgSave.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
      Me.SetControlsEnabled(False)

      'bgwWorker.RunWorkerAsync(JobTypes.Save)

      oFiles = Await Me.GetFilesAsync(Me.Upload.UploadId, Me.Target)
      oChunks = Await Me.GetChunksAsync(oFiles)
      aData = Await Me.MergeChunksAsync(oChunks)

      File.WriteAllBytes(dlgSave.FileName, aData)

      Me.SetControlsEnabled(True)

      MsgBox("Download complete.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Me.Text)
    End If
  End Sub



  Public Async Function GetFilesAsync(UploadId As Integer, Target As Targets) As Task(Of List(Of FileInfo))
    Dim oArgs As ProgressEventArgs

    oArgs = New ProgressEventArgs(0, "Initializing...", ProgressBarStyle.Marquee)
    Me.ReportProgress(Nothing, oArgs)

    Return Await Service.Client.GetFilesAsync(UploadId, Target)
  End Function



  Public Async Function GetChunksAsync(Files As List(Of FileInfo)) As Task(Of SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte()))
    Dim oDownload As Download
    Dim oChunks As SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte())
    Dim aChunks As Chunk()
    Dim oTasks As List(Of Task(Of Chunk))
    Dim oArgs As ProgressEventArgs

    prgProgress.Value = 0

    oArgs = New ProgressEventArgs(Files.Count, "Downloading...", ProgressBarStyle.Continuous)
    oTasks = New List(Of Task(Of Chunk))

    Files.ForEach(Sub(File)
                    oDownload = New Download

                    AddHandler oDownload.Progress, AddressOf ReportProgress

                    oTasks.Add(oDownload.GetChunkAsync(File, Me.Target, oArgs))
                  End Sub)

    aChunks = Await Task.WhenAll(oTasks.ToArray)
    oChunks = New SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte())

    aChunks.ToList.ForEach(Sub(Chunk)
                             oChunks.Add(Chunk.Name, Chunk.Data)
                           End Sub)

    Return oChunks
  End Function



  Public Async Function MergeChunksAsync(Chunks As SortedDictionary(Of String, Byte())) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim oChunks As List(Of Byte())
    Dim iOffset As Integer
    Dim oArgs As ProgressEventArgs
    Dim aData As Byte()

    prgProgress.Value = 0

    oArgs = New ProgressEventArgs(Chunks.Count, "Saving...", ProgressBarStyle.Continuous)

    aData = Await Task.Run(Function()
                             oChunks = Chunks.Select(Function(Pair) Pair.Value).ToList

                             aData = New Byte(oChunks.Sum(Function(Chunk) Chunk.Length) - 1) {}

                             oChunks.ForEach(Sub(Chunk)
                                               Me.ReportProgress(Nothing, oArgs)

                                               Buffer.BlockCopy(Chunk, 0, aData, iOffset, Chunk.Length)

                                               iOffset += Chunk.Length
                                             End Sub)
                             Return aData
                           End Function)

    Return aData
  End Function



  Public Sub ReportProgress(Sender As Download, e As ProgressEventArgs)
    prgProgress.Maximum = e.Maximum
    prgProgress.Style = e.Style

    If e.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee Then
      prgProgress.Value = 0
    Else
      prgProgress.Increment(1)
    End If

    lblStatus.Text = e.Status
  End Sub
End Class



Public Class Download
  Public Event Progress As EventHandler(Of ProgressEventArgs)

  Public Async Function GetChunkAsync(File As FileInfo, Target As Targets, Args As ProgressEventArgs) As Task(Of Chunk)
    Dim oChunk As Chunk

    oChunk = New Chunk
    oChunk.Name = File.Name
    oChunk.Data = Await Service.Client.GetChunkAsync(File, Target)

    RaiseEvent Progress(Me, Args)

    Return oChunk
  End Function
End Class



Public Class Chunk
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Data As Byte()
End Class



Public Class ProgressEventArgs
  Inherits EventArgs

  Public Sub New(Maximum As Integer, Status As String, Style As ProgressBarStyle)
    _Maximum = Maximum
    _Status = Status
    _Style = Style
  End Sub



  Public ReadOnly Property Maximum As Integer
  Public ReadOnly Property Status As String
  Public ReadOnly Property Style As ProgressBarStyle
End Class
```

Comment: you can call an eventhandler from inside the async method no problem?

Comment: @Ewan: I'm not sure I follow you. Could you elaborate? I'm not familiar with how to use `Async/Await` or how to convert `BackgroundWorker` code; I'm looking for some suggestions.

Comment: Note that async/await is not equivalent to `BackgroundWorker`.  For one thing, it doesn't automagically create new threads for you; you have to do that yourself.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898995/102937), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27265877/102937) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15274498/102937).

Comment: @Ewan: Thank you for the example. I've edited my question to provide my workup; it's still not working. Could you have a look and maybe offer a critique? Thanks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thank you for the references. It's a bit clearer now. Can you spot anything in my edited code that's causing the problems I've described? Thanks.

Comment: urg vb :( ok, you are awaiting everything in the click event, your download.getchunk only gets one chunk per file and reports progress once. I was expecting multiple chunks per file. Still I would expect this to download all the files at the same time. Whats service.client maybe that is locking and forcing one at a time?

Comment: @Ewan: Good catch! I just finished discovering that my service wrapper was actually making synchronous calls. I've fixed that and now I make it through only a few async chunk downloads before the UI blocks, network traffic stalls and CPU pegs. And even for those few moments, bandwidth isn't pegged like I would have hoped. How to debug this beast?

Comment: @Ewan: *"I was expecting multiple chunks per file."* The `FileInfo` parameter provides only the name of the chunk that's sitting on the remote server—e.g. 0001.tmp—it doesn't represent the larger file that we'll be building later in the process.

Comment: @Ewan: *"urg vb :("* Yes, I feel the same way about C# and the opposite sex. Can't live with 'em, can't live without 'em  ;-)

Comment: Well i would move the whole loop through the chunks and assemble them at the end to the dowload.getchuncks also im not sure its wise to merge the chuncks in parralell? As to blocking the ui is it win forms? I cmdSave blocks doesnt it?

Comment: Re cpu/network load i think you should look at that client.

Comment: @Ewan: Should we move this to chat? Do you have time?

Comment: I think I have exhausted my vb skills im afriad

Comment: @Ewan: No problem, you've managed to push me over the hill on this one. I'll work out the rest. Thank you!

Comment: @Ewan: One final clarification please...  you've stated a caution against parallelism during chunk merge, but I was under the impression that—while the encompassing task is running asynchronously—that the merge itself is running in a synchronous loop. Please correct me.

Comment: Ahh maybe i was just confused by the await task.run

Comment: @Ewan: *"...confused..."* Funny, that's never happened to *me*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class Download
    {
        public EventHandler<int> Progress;
        public async Task GetData(string url)
        {
            int percentDone = 0;
            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
            {
                //get data
                //write data to disk?
                if(Progress != null)
                {
                    Progress(this, percentDone);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ManyDownloads
    {
        public void ReportProgress(object sender, int progress)
        {
            //update the UI
        }
        public List<Download> Downloads { get; set; }
        public void DownloadAll(List<string> Urls)
        {
            this.Downloads = new List<Download>();
            foreach(var url in Urls)
            {
                var d = new Download();
                d.Progress += ReportProgress;
                d.GetData(url); //dont await will run async
                this.Downloads.Add(d); //keep hold of the download object so you can refernce it in ReportProgress if needed
            }

        }
    }
```

---

if you need the return value of the function you can add all the tasks to an array and use await Task.WhenAll or Task.WaitAll

```
public async Task DownloadAll(List<string> Urls)
{
    List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    this.Downloads = new List<Download>();
    foreach(var url in Urls)
    {
        var d = new Download();
        d.Progress += ReportProgress;
        tasks.Add(d.GetData(url)); //dont await will run async
    }
    //tasks are all running in threads at this point
    await Task.WhenAll<string>(tasks.ToArray()); //wait for all the tasks to complete before continuing

    foreach(var t in tasks)
    {
        //save data
        File.WriteAllText(t.Result, "filename.txt"); //todo::check for exceptions
    }
}
```

Update re comments:

The confusion is that the async keyword on the GetData function adds no functionality to the pseudo code. without an await within that function the code **in that function** executes synchronously. (I added the async because I assumed that the actual download chunk code will include an await.)

However! we don't particularly care in this case about the code in the function. We want to run the whole function multiple times in parallel. Calling a Task function without awaiting it in the DownloadAll method creates **and runs** a new Task for each download.

You have to be careful not to dispose of these Tasks before they are completed though. If you just ran the first set of code in a console app the app would start all the downloads and then finish and exit before they completed.

Comment: This won't work.  You have no await in GetData, so there is no place for GetData to return while work is being done.  It will therefore run synchronously.

Comment: Im assuming the download saves to disk rather than returning the data. GetData will run On all the download objects at the same time because you dont await the call. If you need the return value you can add the tasks to an array and do Task.WaitAll

Comment: The `async` keyword doesn't do anything, by itself.  All it does is enable use of the `await` keyword within a method so decorated.  From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx): *"The method runs synchronously until it reaches its first **await** expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited task is complete. In the meantime, control returns to the caller of the method."*

Comment: exactly, you _could_ await each download to finsih before starting the next, but you dont want to, so you dont await it

Comment: You don't understand how this works.  `await` doesn't mean "wait;"  it means "sign the following code up onto a continuation, and return control to the caller."  Read the article I linked above, and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).

Comment: dude, run the code

Comment: Dude, listen to what I am saying.  Your edit might work, but not for the reasons you think it does.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. sure the async on GetData does nothing (unless you use it in your chunk download),  but it doesn't matter because you are returning a Task

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41659/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-ewan).

Comment: Consider implementing the IProgress interface on both classes.

Comment: Even though you already `await`ed `WhenAll`, it's still "best practice" to never invoke `Task.Result` in `async` code, since it makes errors more likely if the code is ever refactored. prefer just `await`ing the single task, it won't incur any additional overhead since the task is already marked as completed.

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely clear on where your discussion ended, but there is absolutely no reason at all to spawn threads when doing asynchronous IO. threads are for CPU bound work that can be parallelized (and surely for some other things as well).

Comment: you can use task.result in a continuation which in effect this is. however, yes I prefer my first version where you would add the result to the download object.

Comment: a Task isnt a thread. but this goes a bit deeper than the OQ

Comment: @Ewan yes, you CAN use Result after a task is awaited, but Result is still a blocking call, even if it returns immediately. this means that it's easier to mess things up if you move statements around. it'd be "safer" and "more idiomatic" to replace your last line with `File.WriteAllText(await t, "filename.txt");` (there's async file IO apis too by the way, no? this method is blocking.)

Comment: await the task twice? interesting approach could work, haven't tried.